# Using Selenium to navigate to a url after sign-up causes a "whoops" html page to appear

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium

I am trying to build tests for my website using selenium, my site is built on django and therefor has test cases built in.

I am using djangos LiveServerTestCase as their docs suggest for Selenium. I've managed to get the test cases running using this code

```
import sys
2 
3 from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
4 
5 #selenium webdriver for web simulation and testing
6 from selenium import webdriver
7 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
8 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
9 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
10 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
11 from users.models import User
12 
13 class DashboardTestCases(LiveServerTestCase):
14     
15     @classmethod
16     def setUpClass(cls):
17         cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
18         super(DashboardTestCases, cls).setUpClass()
19     
20     @classmethod
21     def tearDownClass(cls):
22         super(DashboardTestCases, cls).tearDownClass()
23         user = User.objects.filter(username="test")
24         if user.exists():
25             user.delete()
26         cls.driver.quit()
27     
28     def test_base(self):
29         self.driver.get(self.live_server_url)
30         self.assertIn("neury", self.driver.title)
31     
32     def test_sign_in(self):
33         user = User.objects.create_superuser("test", "test@test.com", "test123")
34         print(user.username)
35         self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/admin/'))
36         user = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')
37         user.send_keys('test')
38         password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')
39         password.send_keys('test123')
40         submit = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('grp-button')
41         submit.click()
42         try:
43             element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
44                     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'grp_admin_title'))
45                     )
46         finally:
47             self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/datasets/'))
```

This checks the initial home page loads, then the user is created and can sign in to the admin page. But when i try to then go to the /datasets/ link, i get an error in the browser which is just an HTML screen saying "whoops" I presumed this was because i was re-driecting too fast, so i added the wait clause in to wait for the django admin-id-title to be found before it re-driects. But this has not solved the problem.

[image: an image of what the "whoops" screen looks like.]

Does anybody know what this error could be and how i can stop this from happening?!

Comment: What happens if you don't re-direct?

Comment: This woops is a error 500 page? Can you test with DEBUG=True so we can get a stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Hi, if i don't redirect at the end it just completes the tests and finishes. Even if i create a separate method that just tries to access the /accounts/login/ page or /datasets/ i get the same error?

Comment: I have also just set DEBUG = True in my UnitTests class in settings, but it still doesn't give me anymore detail on the error, just the same whoops page

Comment: @adds68 Why i don't see the redirected url your browser screenshot? It just showing login url.

Comment: It's not a django redirect i just tell the browser to go to another view once this one has finished on lines 46/47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clarify this post, i have managed to fix this.

Debug = True, does not work in the standard settings file, you have to provide this in your **init** method for the testclass you are building, like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(FOOTestCases, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     if settings.DEBUG == False:
         settings.DEBUG = True
```

This will then provide you with the correct error messages and stack trace through selenium, for you to then debug.